# Why do I get an OGR error when attempting to save an edited Shapefile?

Tags: qgis, ogr

I often get an ogr error when I try to save a shapefile after working on it in Qgis ( adding features, removing, modifying attributes.. )

The error says :
`"OGR ERROR : Attempt to delete shape with feature id (-28 ) which does not exist"`

Does anyone have an idea about the reason why I'm getting this error and/or how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 4):

I think you will not get this error if you `Save` between adding and removing features.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, using save between each operation may solve the problem but when working with a large number of features and a considerable amount of operation it becomes "annoying" to have to save changes to the shapefile after each action!

Comment: Ok, then try the 'Save' always before deleting anything. Until you save, the features are only stored in memory, with negative ID. 'Save' might try to save and delete them in one step, which causes the error message. Same goes to adding and deleting table columns.

Comment: Yes unfortunately QGIS + Shapefiles  does not queue transactions very well at all and as such, its most likely a 'delete > add' action on the same record ID or something similar as mentioned above......., and yer, it just doesn't like that. If you are working with a large number of features and larger numbers of edits, then I would also suggest moving away from shapefiles and implement a database, which can handle transactions better.

Comment: For that reason, QGIS favours geopackages as the standard format by now. The question is about 8 years old now!

Answer (score 0):

I Set M Values. I am editing from an ArcGIS fgdb and the OGR error stated an m value issue. Set M Values fixed the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try the fix geometries tool - it fixed a persistent 'OGR [3] error1' error for me

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Please click 'edit' and update your post with more information about how to apply the fix geometries tool - how it works (command line? Example?) and what it can fix.